# Angular unit test Spinner Interceptor

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have a interceptor for http request. For every http request spinner is showing.

And I want to write a unit test for this interceptor  to check if the `spinnerServiceSpy.show` and `spinnerServiceSpy.hide` are properly called.

```
export class SpinnerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
requestCount = 0;
constructor(private spinnerService: SpinnerService) { }

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.requestCount++;

        this.spinnerService.show();

    return next.handle(request)
        .pipe(
            finalize(() => {
                this.requestCount--;
                if (this.requestCount === 0) {
                    this.spinnerService.hide();
                }
            })
        );
}
}
```

As you can see this function is called from the finalize() RxJS operator. The unit test for this interceptor is as follow:

```
describe(`SpinnerInterceptor`, () => {
let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
let service: ApiService;
let interceptor: SpinnerInterceptor;
const spinnerServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('SpinnerService', ['show', 'hide']);

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        providers: [
            ApiService,
            SpinnerInterceptor,
            { provide: SpinnerService, useValue: spinnerServiceSpy },
            { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: SpinnerInterceptor, multi: true }
        ],
    });
    interceptor = TestBed.get(SpinnerInterceptor);
    service = TestBed.get(ApiService);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
});

it('should hide spinner', () => {
    service.getCountRecords('Faculty')
    .pipe(
        finalize(() => expect(spinnerServiceSpy.hide).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)))
        .subscribe(res => {
            expect(spinnerServiceSpy.show).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        });
    httpMock.expectOne('Faculty/countRecords').flush({});
});
```

});

But i get the following error `Expected spy SpinnerService.hide to have been called once. It was called 0 times.`

Comment: In the actual code, put a `console.log('In finalize block')` in the `finalize` block as well as a `console.log('hiding spinner...')` in the `if` block and ensure you see both logs.

Comment: Yes, i see both logs, but finalize is first that why i getting this error. I think  it's problem in asynchronous code, but I don't know how i can deal with it

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
it('should hide spinner', async done => {
  await service.getCountRecords('Faculty').pipe(
    take(1), 
  ).toPromise()
   .then(res => {
      expect(spinnerServiceSpy.hide).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(spinnerServiceSpy.show).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      done();
  });
  httpMock.expectOne('Faculty/countRecords').flush({});
});
```